# Superset stability on windows linux subsystem

Tags: apache-superset

We have been using JasperReports (community edition) and its working fine. But we need to implement interactive reports (which are not supported by community edition)

I have been looking for a simple solution for my reports and came across apache superset. I have installed the superset on Windows linux subsystem (we are a windows shop), i have few question and hopefully you guys can answer that:

- Is it stable to install superset on windows linux subsystem for production environment?
- Can superset works on just plain oracle relation data?

If there are any other open source project i should look into please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but: if the need is that pressing, and you're working for a company (at least, that's what it sounds like you're trying to solve this for?) why not just pay them to get the features you need if their product is clearly working for you already?

Comment: Also, why would you want to add all the complexity of WSL into production environment, instead of just using Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a committer to the Superset project. Unfortunately Superset isn't officially supported on Windows (or even WSL). It may work but the community hasn't created a set of best practices / recommendations here nor is Windows actively tested as part of the development process.

But Superset has been tested against many Linux flavors, so that's probably your best bet.

Also, can you clarify what you mean by "plain oracle relation data"? The Superset community has added the following documentation for working with Oracle SQL databases: https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/oracle

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We have decided to go with knowage server  and eclipse birt reporting for the reporting need. It fulfills our reporting requirements.